# Problema com o pyinstaller+ os.getcwd() no MAC OS

Tags: python, osx, mac, pyinstaller

Depois de inúmeros problemas com Tkinter e o Pyinstaller, finalmente consegui fazer uma aplicação executável Unix funcionar normalmente no MAC High Sierra. Porém dentro da pasta da minha aplicação, existe uma pasta chamada script, que uso `chdir(os.getcdw()+'/scritp')` para abrir-la.

O problema é justamente na utilização do executável para Mac OS feito com pyinstaller. Quando eu clico em tal executável, ele entende que  `os.getcdw()` é justamente a pasta do usuário. Ele não pega a pasta onde está o arquivo do executável.

Por exemplo, ao invés de `os.getcdw()` ser igual a `"/Users/isaacvictor/Desktop/scriexe"`

ele retorna `"/Users/isaacvictor"`

Como eu faço para resolver este problema? Eu quero pegar a pasta do arquivo executável.

Muito obrigado a todos que contribuirem.

Comment: O `os.getcwd()` retorna o diretório de trabalho atual, se quiser usar outro você pode abrir, algo como: `meu_dir = os.open( "/Users/isaacvictor/Desktop/", os.O_RDONLY )`, e depois setar ele como seu dir de trabalho padrão : `os.fchdir(meu_dir)`, quando chamar o `os.getcwd()` vai funcionar.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim interessante, qual a diferença de abrir um *fd* pro diretório, do que  simplesmente usar `os.chdir("/Users/isaacvictor/Desktop/")` diretamente? Acho que é a mesma coisa, fica bem mais complexo.

Comment: Então @nosklo sugeri essa opção porque foi a primeira que pensei. Quanto a sua pergunta, dando uma olhada na [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fchdir) (em um cenário para Linux)temos que os dois são praticamente idênticos, exceto pelo fato de que o `os.fchdir()` recebe um *fd*. Isso implica que não somente diretórios podem ser passados por parâmetro, já que no Linux tudo é tratado como arquivo, logo *sockets* e dispositivos podem ser abertos e o seu *fd* recuperado, assim dando para realizar operações sobre eles. Então pra esse caso o `os.chdir()` é a melhor solução ;)

Comment: Complementando: a partir da [versão 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#os) do Python o `os.chdir()` também suporta o *file descriptor* como entrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pode ver na documentação [aqui](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/runtime-information.html), durante a execução de um programa congelado com `pyinstaller` o caminho do executável fica em `sys.executable` - o problema é que isso não acontece quando você roda o script em formato `.py`, somente no executável;

Porém existe uma solução, você pode verificar a variável especial `sys.frozen` para saber se está rodando o executável ou não:

```
import os
import sys

def pega_caminho_script():
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) :
        # rodando executavel
        caminho = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
    else:
        # rodando py
        caminho = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    return caminho
```

Essa função vai retornar o caminho para o arquivo .py ou para o .exe, dependendo da forma que está sendo executado o programa, antes ou depois do `pyinstaller`.